# Converting a hexadecimal to a decimal value using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am completely stumped on this one.  I have to utilize the current code structure to convert a user-entered hexadecimal value into a decimal value using recursion.  The method header for the recursive call cannot be changed.  I have this figured out without the use of recursion, but for the life of me cannot wrap my head around how I would do this.

//  EDIT -- SOLVED

```
public class hextodecimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Test out the parsing with values from page 719
        System.out.println(hexToDecimal("7F"));
        System.out.println(hexToDecimal("FFFF"));
        System.out.println(hexToDecimal("431"));
    }

    public static int hexToDecimal(String hexString) {
        return hexToDecimal(hexString, 0, hexString.length() - 1);
    }

    public static int hexToDecimal(String hexString, int end, int hexLength) {
        if (hexLength < end)
            return 0;
        else {
            int decValue;
        if (hexString.charAt(hexLength) == 'A')
            decValue = 10;
        else if (hexString.charAt(hexLength) == 'B')
            decValue = 11;
        else if (hexString.charAt(hexLength) == 'C')
            decValue = 12;
        else if (hexString.charAt(hexLength) == 'D')
            decValue = 13;
        else if (hexString.charAt(hexLength) == 'E')
            decValue = 14;
        else if (hexString.charAt(hexLength) == 'F')
            decValue = 15;
        else
            decValue = hexString.charAt(hexLength) - '0';

        return hexToDecimal(hexString, end, hexLength - 1) * 16
            + decValue;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? please add the [tag:homework] tag if it is. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but was this code provided for you already?

Comment: Does it have to be recursive, or are you just wanting it to be thinking that it might help? Not to mention that code already implements the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only two choices.  Process the leftmost char, and pass substring(1) to yourself recursively, or process the rightmost char, and pass what's to the left to yourself recursively.  That should be enough of a hint.

Comment: Are you sure you'd be able to process from the right? And @MISMajorDeveloperAnyways I posted an answer just after you accepted one, you can read it anyway if you want more info about how to go about it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you could process from the right.  Ignoring the termination checks, it would be, conceptually, `valueOfRightmost + 16*callMyselfrecursively(allExceptTheRightDigit);`  Sounds like the next homework question - solve it the opposite way from the way you solved it last time.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you *have to* use recursion, and you *can't* use `Integer.parseInt()` (which you already know about and would defeat the purpose of asking a question), this is how you could go about it:

When creating a recursive function, you need a terminating condition, and a way of getting to that terminating condition. Since you apparently have to use that method signature, your terminating condition is going to have to be once `hexString` is empty, after having passed a `String` of 1 less character at each recursion.

If `hexString` is empty, it'd make sense to return 0 (it might make more sense if you read the below first).

You should process the most significant digit each time, and multiply the parsed value by `16 ^ (length_of hexString - 1)`. 16 because hex is base 16, and raising that to the power of the digit position - 1 for the same reason you would do 10^X in decimal once you have the digit and it's position (ie. tens, hundreds, thousands). The length of the `String` gives us this position. *Look at the example at the bottom if you don't understand what I mean.*

Now you need a way of parsing this character. A simple way is to use a `Map` to map each hex `char` to an `int` of it's decimal representation, but you could also use `if` or `switch` statements. If the `char` is not a valid hexadecimal digit, throw an exception.

Once you have this value, add it to the return value of `hexToDecimal`, ie. `value + hexToDecimal()`. The `String` being passed to `hexToDecimal` is the current string modified to the range `[1, length]`, where (as I mentioned above) the first character is chopped off.

**NOTE:** Think about why you can't process from the least significant digit (right) using that method signature. How would you be able multiply the hex digit based on it's position to give it the correct value?

ie. `7F`, which is 127 in decimal.

- 0x7 = 7
- 0xF = 15

The number is **not** 7 + 15, but 7*(16^1) + 15!

Comment: Nice explanation.  One minor addition - convert the input to all uppercase (or lowercase if you prefer) to simplify the if/case/map.

Comment: @MISMajorDeveloperAnyways: If you read this, take that case of the letters into account, you should be able to work that out.

Answer (score 1):

RTFM! Here an enhanced excerpt from the [javadoc for Integer.parseInt(String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> Parses the string argument as a signed [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) in the [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) specified by the second argument.

Comment: -1 for just pasting in the Java docs.  The question was how to parse a hex string using recursion.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I probably deserved the -1 - I've trimmed it. However, OP code is *not* recursive - it's a bogus question.

Comment: I took the OP to mean "Here's my non-recursive code, but my homework assignment is to use recursion and that's where I'm stuck" - I think it's a totally reasonable question.  I was working on my own answer but looks like one has already been accepted, doh!

Comment: Question was regarding rewriting the code to be recursive.  My Posted solution was without recursion.  I'm still stuck, but I have some clue as to what I need to do.  I am running into an issue figuring the incremental powers though (e.g. 7F = 7 x 16 + 15 x (1))

Comment: @MISMajorDeveloperAnyways process from the left and use the length of the string - 1 as the power. I added an answer after you accepted that still might have some use to you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is to realize the significance of each digit.  For example, `F00D` in hex is:

```
F * (16 ^ 3) //Fourth digit
plus
0 * (16 ^ 2) //Third digit
plus
0 * (16 ^ 1) //Second digit
plus
D * (16 ^ 0) //First digit
```

In other words:

```
(15 * (16^3)) + 0 + 0 + 13
```

Or:

```
61440 + 0 + 0 + 13 = 61453
```

So at each step, you raise 16 to the power of its place in the sequence.

You can use the length of your string to figure out what place you're at, and pass the remaining digits to the next iteration.  Each function will recursively add to the result.

For example:

1. The first iteration will take `F00D` and return `61440 + hexToDecimal("00D")`
2. The second iteration will take `00D` and return `0 + hexToDecimal("0D")`
3. The third iteration will take `0D` and return `0 + hexToDecimal("D")`
4. The fourth iteration will take `D` and return `13`, and not call itself anymore since the length of the string is 1.

Now just to write the code! :)

Comment: I am just glad the semester is over.  I'm not a huge fan of doing homework at midnight.  I am new here, so I will remember the homework tag in the future.  I posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a 1 digit hexadecimal number (0-F), then it would be easy to parse.  You could do it with a switch.

If it was a n>1 digit hexadecimal number then it is too hard.  Split it into two numbers - a n-1 digit number and a 1 digit number.